# Why MoveFile is missing operator?

Tags: delphi

I tried in many ways to copy / clone a file and paste it into another directory, this was a unique way that only gave one error

```
procedure TDelForm.moveFileClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if OpenDialog1.Execute then
  begin
    edit1.Text:=OpenDialog1.FileName;
    SaveDialog1.FileName:=OpenDialog1.FileName;
  end;

  if SaveDialog1.Execute then
    edit2.Text:=SaveDialog1.FileName;

  MoveFile(pchar(edit1.Text), pchar(edit2.Text));                         
end;
```

Unit1.pas(46): E2066 Missing operator or semicolon

Unit1.pas(46): E2014 Statement expected, but expression of type 'TButton' found

Comment: My psychic powers tell me that you have a button named MoveFile, which hides the function with the same name that you're trying to call. Rename the button to btnMoveFile, or similar.

Comment: It helps to prepend button names with text like 'btn.'

Comment: On a side note, supporting RJ's comment, you seriously need to prefix all your component names. The prefix should reflect the class name in some way, so buttons would be `btn`, for example, making this `btnMoveFile`. Labels could be prefixed `lbl`, lists can be prefixed `lst`, grids can be prefixed `grd`, and so on. But the idea is to make the name as unique as possible, without making it overly-complicated either. You wouldn't want to name something `grdGridThatContainsMyDetailedData`. Just `grdMyData` would be enough.

Comment: The only exception is those controls which are like major fixtures. For example, when I implement a status bar, I typically name it `Stat`. It both describes the class, and gives me a unique name which doesn't clash with anything. Or if a form has a primary grid, I may name it `Grid`, `Grd`, or even just `G` in some cases. Depends on the implementation.

Comment: @JerryDodge Is it a Delphi Idiom to do that, because I do Suffix not prefix with names.

Answer (score 8):

Based on the name of the event handler (`moveFileClick`) and the way the IDE names things, you have a button named `moveFile` on your form that is conflicting with the function name. The compiler thinks `MoveFile` refers to the button, and is looking for a dot followed by a property or method. Rename the button, or explicitly resolve the call to `MoveFile` by referencing it as `SysUtils.MoveFile()`.

```
SysUtils.MoveFile(PChar(edit1.Text), PChar(edit2.Text));
```

Comment: Just a thought, OP might be coming from a case-sensitive language, where it would have been perfectly legal to name them different cases. Of course still not recommended though.

Comment: Then again, `edit1` and `edit2` kinda contradict that theory.

Comment: @JerryDodge: Possible, but unlikely based on the name of that `moveFileClick` event handler. And no matter anyway; all flavors of Pascal (including Delphi's Object Pascal) are case-insensitive, and the question is about Delphi.

Comment: Depending on Delphi version, this might have to be _System.SysUtils.MoveFile_ instead.